# CSS fix div after scroll with negative margin jump

Tags: html, css, scroll, web

I'd like that when i fix the element after scroll **with negative margin** this not "jump".
Example -> https://jsfiddle.net/uxhgpz6e/2/

```
enter code here.header-body {
    background: #339CCC;
    border-top: 5px solid #EDEDED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1001;
    padding-top:90px;
    transition: all 5s ease;
}`
```

(I accentuated the behavior with the transition)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but would this work?: https://jsfiddle.net/m9oqbuab/1/

Essentially, it's always fixed. Added the following to the css under `.header-body`:

```
.header-body {
    background: #339CCC;
    border-top: 5px solid #EDEDED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1001;
    padding-top:90px;
    transition: all 5s ease;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Afterwards, removed the `css('position')` methods from the js.